# is there a function in excel can help me to increase and decrease fraction of money value to a specific small changes?

Tags: excel, ms-office

[image: photo of table explain more]

```
 IQD 242,200        if the last three digits is nearer to 250, make it 250 or if it's nearer to 0 then make it 000)
 IQD 242,350        if the last three digits is nearer to 500, make it 500 or if it's nearer to 250 then make it 250)
 IQD 242,700        if the last three digits is nearer to 750, make it 750 or if it's nearer to 500 then make it 500)
 IQD 242,900        if the last three digits is nearer to 1000, make it 1000 or if it's nearer to 750 then make it 750)
```

Comment: Please try to search for a function that changes values and add an example of your formula so others can help you more quickly. Just asking for a formula doesn't do much. As a starting point you can try and use the [FLOOR](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-floor-function) function in Excel or even the [ROUND](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/round-a-number-f82b440b-689d-4221-b21e-38da99d33435?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Answer (score 1):

If the amounts are stored as numbers (with IQD being added through number formatting), then:

```
=MROUND(A1,250)
```

If the amounts are stored as text (with IQD and the amount being a literal string), then:

```
="IQD "&TEXT(MROUND(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-4),250),"#,##0")
```

Comment: hi dear @Michael thanks a lot . it worked perfectly. but how can the other three first digits be added too ?

Comment: They're already included. If it's not giving you what you want, then please give an example of what exactly you're expecting so that we understand what you want.